# How to hide a div on certain pages using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have just finished creating my new template layout for my website. I want to use the same layout on my login page, but there are two divs that use use the URL CSS coding for images, but I dont want them to be shown on the login page.
How can I hide these divs using CSS without using a `style` tag in the login page to over ride the CSS file?

Here is an example of the basic layout:

```
example css{
  background-image: url("paper.gif"); 
}

<div class="example div">
```

Now all I want is that example `div` to not show in login.php.
Please note that I'm using PHP include to grab my template files for my website.
Another idea, could I do something like this?

```
If(index.php){
  div example{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `style` as a property of a div

```
<div class="example div" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

this will require to create a new layout .

or you can just use this js code in the login page

```
document.getElementById('hdiv').style.visibility="hidden";
```

and just add an id for the div. or you might use `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: if i use js for this can i define it to only work on login.php sorry for the stupid question i not got around to learning js and jquery for my website because i been told that they can be used to mess with website security

Comment: Here they won't mess up with your website security because what this code does is related only to the design and not to something like php injection or reaching some secret information. If what you do is requiring php files to `login.php` then to add this `js` code you must print this code in `<script>` and `</script>` tags only in this page before closing the `<body>` tag.

Comment: so as long as i use js for related designs only my websites security is not affected

Comment: not only for related designs only! When you use `JS ` for making a HTML canvas game using `js` that won't affect your security since html and js are static and nobody can change them in your server. The security issues are related to PHP and SQL when people try to access your database and know what are the users passwords or personal informations.

Answer (score 0):

If your login.php page has a custom class for the `body` element or if you're able to add one try this:

```
body .example.div
{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define another css class for hiding:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
`<div class="example div" style="display:none;">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="display:none">
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
div.example.div {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: i have never learnt pseudo css look and sounds like a complex css coding

Comment: For divs just display none using css, and if the divs have same classes then use css pseudo classes.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I had a LAYOUT file where I had a navigation pane such as "Home" and "About" - but I did not want these visible on the "Login" page. Below is my solution (I have researched and researched and found nothing).

LAYOUT FILE:

```
    <body>
    <div>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/About">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <footer>
            &copy;@DateTime.Now.Year - LinkNChain
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

LOGIN PAGE:

```
<style>header {display: none;}</style>
```